# How to interact with multiple web pages simultaneously

Tags: javascript, scripting, browser-automation

I'm looking for methods to interact with multiple pages simultaneously. In my case I have several pages that accept user input as keystrokes, and I would like to be able to trigger all of them.

Any ideas?

Automater? putting multiple tabs in focus simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it "simultaneously". Only one thing can have focus at a time.  Your options are: to interact with them sequentially (fast enough that it seems simultaneous.) Or, you could write an application that gets all of the window handles, and sends them the keypress messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do some sort of data entry and speed up the things by opening multiple pages, you could try one of the following

- imacros
- Greasemonkey addon for firefox with your custom script.

There are other methods also to do this thing.

If you are a programmer, you could write a simple application which will post data to the page. In that way, you will not even have to open the page.